# Form's caption in Dynamics AX 2012 R2

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, caption

I have a problem which take me so long to find the solution but I still not find out.

I have 2 form :

*FormA* (caller) have data source is *HcmWorker* table.

*FormB* (called) have data source is table B ( table B have relation with *HcmWorker* table on field tableB.fieldA = HcmWorker.RecID).

When I call *formB* from *formA*, *formB* always have caption is personnel number of *HcmWorker* record, although I don't set up *TitleDatasource* property or *Caption* property on *formB*.

*FormB* only have query data range to filter list of records of *tableB* according by *HcmWorker* records.

So, I dont know why do the personnel number of *HcmWorker* record appears on form's caption. How do I remove it ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Then, what is your question?

Comment: Hi Jan, i edited my post. How do i remove the personnel number out of my form's caption ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it works that way because you have nothing in `Title datasource` property of your `formB` design. If you set the `Title datasource` for your `formB` -- this will change the form caption and this will not come from the `HcmWorker` anymore but from a linked `tableB` instead.

Comment: Also, you can set the caption yourself: `this.caption("Whatever");` 
This can be done in the `linkActive` to override the default.

Comment: Thank you Alex.
Thank you Jan.